# I'm trying to add up every single JTextFrame and I keep looping forever?

Tags: java, paint

I am trying to add up every single `JTextFrame` box and whenever I do it either adds to infinity or repeats the same numbers in a loop. I tried setting the total variable back to `0` but that didn't help much. Any ideas?

```
while(true) {
    int total = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < expenseArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if(expenseArray[i].getText() == "" || expenseArray[i].getText() == " ") {
            total += 0; 
        }
        else {
            total = sumArray(expenseArray, 0); 
            System.out.println(total);
            expenseArray[expenseArray.length - 1].setText(String.valueOf(total));
        }
    }
    
    total = 0;
    expenseArray[expenseArray.length - 1].setText(String.valueOf(total));
}
```

Comment: why the `while (true)`?

Comment: the reason for the while true is so it will keep updating the new values instead of it going through the for loop once and ending.

Comment: What new values? The new value from user? You might wanna use some sort of listener rather than while true. That while loops is messing your code.

Comment: Also I am pretty sure if this while loop is executed in same thread as UI. It will freeze the UI.

Comment: What do you mean by the same thread as the UI? The same loop? The same function?

Comment: What is a "JTextFrame". I've heard of a `JTextField` or a `JFrame`. Ask a question that is clear so we don't have to guess what you are talking about. Post a proper [mre] to clarify the question.